# Apostrophes in sentences with implied words

Tags: phrases, american-english, apostrophe

From a card game where the question is:

> How many apostrophes are in the following sentence?
>
> "Thats a bigger car than any of my brothers friends."

Does "friends" need an apostrophe because the implied phrase is "than any of my brother's friends' cars are."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it uses vulgar language.

Comment: "That's a better excuse than my brother / my brothers / my brother's" ... which is correct (speaking of a single brother)? Extend to "That's a better excuse than my brother's friend's "

Answer (score 1):

The *s'* ending to a word is used when both of two conditions are met:

- The noun is being ascribed possession of something.

  - If only this condition is met, we just add *'s*.
- The noun is a plural.

  - If only this condition is met, we just add *s*, *es*, *ies*, etc.

In your case, the... *schmeckels* belong to the friends and there are several friends, so both conditions are met for *friends*. That said, we're talking about the friends of a single brother, so *brother's* is only possessive and not plural. The correct ending is therefore:

> ...than any of my brother's friends'.

It might be easier to see by making the sentence a bit more verbose:

> That's a bigger schmeckel than any of my brother Mike's several friends' schmeckels.

Note that *That's* needs an apostrophe, too, to denote the contraction of *That is*.

Comment: But the sibling could have more than one brother, so making it "brothers' friends'. . . ." It's also possible that  a singular friend has more than one oversized rooster, which would make it "brothers' friend's (roosters).

Comment: It could also be true in various ways, some of them vulgar, that the brother's friends might _be_ cocks rather that _owning_ cocks. In that case 'friends' would not be possessive. The question is not only potentially vulgar but also ambiguous.